# Each of eight, consecutive, three digit numbers is divisble by its last digit. What is the sum of digits of the smallest number?

Tags: number-theory

> Each of eight, consecutive, three digit numbers is divisble by its last digit. What is the sum of digits of the smallest number?

#### My approach:

Each number we can denote like that:

$\overline{abc},\ \overline{abc}+1,\ ...,\ \overline{abc}+7\quad$
,where$\ \overline{abc} \;$is the smallest.

Sum of these numbers: $\ 8(a+b+c)+28$

Also each number has the same second from the last digit, because there is no number divisble by $0$. That means sequance starts with number ending with digit $1\,$ or $2$.

This question is from this year's Kangaroo competition.

Comment: Isn't it 28, not 27?

Comment: I solved your problem, but is this a current contest problem?

Comment: No, do not worry. It is from yesterday.

Comment: So submissions are fully closed for this question? Any way to independently verify this please? Looks like a Singapore based competition. And I'm a Singaporean myself.

Comment: @Deepak It is from Poland. Maybe it is not proof, but answer is probabaly 13 (number 841). I found that on the internet but without analitycal deduction.

Comment: @Deepak This is kangorro site https://www.kangur-mat.pl/index.php. You can see there that all competition was already held or are about to be (There is no contest 30.05.20)

Comment: OK, fair enough. I posted my solution. It's quite easy (I did it mentally).

Comment: It was in category junior- it was predisposed for 16-years old, so maybe that is why it was easy, haha. I assume you are older

Comment: Yes. Don't ask how much older. :)

Comment: I wonder if this is a related competition: https://mathkangaroo.sg/

Comment: @Deepak Yes, both descend from http://www.aksf.org/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108668/discussion-between-1qwertyyyy-and-deepak).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have observed, you cannot have any number ending with a $0$, so your first two digits are fixed.

Division tests for numbers ending with $1,2,5,6$ add no information.

From the division test for $3$, you know that the first two digits must sum to a multiple of $3$.

From the division test for $7$, you know that the number obtained by truncating the last digit and subtracting away twice the last digit from it will give a multiple of $7$. This means that the first two digits have to also be a multiple of $7$.

From these two conditions, the first two digits must be a multiple of $21$, which means they can be $21,42,63,84$.

From the division test for $4$, you know the last two digits must form a number divisible by $4$.

The only one that fits this condition is the first two digits $84$.

So the smallest number is $841$, digit sum $13$.

For rigour, you need to exclude the possibility of the sequence starting with first digit $2$. If this were the case, the final number would end with $9$, and the division test for $9$ demands the sum of the first two digits should also be a multiple of $9$. But this would mean that $63$ is the only possibility, which would conflict with the rule for the last digit $4$ ($34$ is not a multiple of $4$). So we have verified that the above is the only sequence of numbers that meets the criteria.

Comment: The divisibility test for $7$ is not as widely known as for the other single digit divisors, so here's a more detailed explanation: https://www.aaamath.com/div66_x7.htm#:~:text=To%20determine%20if%20a%20number,to%20be%20repeated%20several%20times.

Comment: Deepak, it's simpler than that: $100a+10b+7$ is divisible by $7$ if and only if $100a+10b$ is, which is divisible by $7$ if and only if $10a+b$ is.

Comment: @TonyK Sure, but this is how I thought about it instinctively when I did my mental working, so I put it down that way. The divisibility rule works for any last digit, but with a last digit of $7$, the initial two digits make a number divisible by $7$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if the number is $\overline{abc} = 100a + 10b + c$, for it to be divisible by $c$ means $c \mid 100a + 10b$. As such, since $100a + 10b$ is the same for all $8$ numbers, to have it be divisible by their $8$ last digits means the $\operatorname{lcm}$ of those digits must divide $100a + 10b$.

Next, as you stated, the first ending digit must be either $1$, so it goes to $8$, or $2$, in which case it goes to $9$. For the first case, you have

$$\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) = 8(7)(5)(3) = 840 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$\operatorname{lcm}(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) = 9(8)(7)(5) = 2\text{,}520 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

However, $100a + 10b \lt 991$, so \eqref{eq1A} must be true, giving that the smallest number is $841$, with a digit sum of $8 + 4 + 1 = 13$.

Comment: I think you're missing out a $4$ from both sets of digits you're doing the lcm on. Doesn't affect the result but you may want to correct that.

Comment: @Deepak You're right. Thanks for pointing it out. I've now fixed those typos.